# How to return three 3d arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a `C` function to perform some vector calculations and generate three separate 3d `arrays`. I allocate the `arrays` at the beginning of the function

```
double fac_x[Ny][Nx][Nz];
double fac_y[Ny][Nx][Nz];
double fac_z[Ny][Nx][Nz];
```

then fill them in with calculated values.

How can I return all three of these arrays? What does the function prototype need to look like?

Comment: Put all 3 in a `struct` and return that.  But suggest instead to have the caller pass in the address of where to save the results instead.  Posting an example, even in pseudo code, would help clarify your goals.

Comment: @chux In that case we would have to pass quadruple pointers, right? @M. Baum: Are you sure that you really want to use 3D arrays in C? Unless the sizes `Nx,Ny` and `Nz` are known at compile time, the memory management can become very messy.

Comment: @cthl pass quadruple pointers would be one way to do it, though not that advisable.  A good answer needs more info from OP like the nature/use of `Ny, Nx, Nz` as you commented.  Without that detail, this is too broad.

Comment: @chux Yes, the quadruple pointer is very poor, so my question was not fully serious.
Allocating the arrays within the function might also be a bad idea, because then the allocation and deallocation happens at different levels of abstraction.

Comment: I'm writing these functions to interface with a `Python` package. Each time they are called `Nx`, `Ny`, and `Nz` will be known. Seems like it will be easiest to pass references to the functions.

Comment: @M.Baum Nice you described your code a bit in a comment.  Even better to _post_ code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of options :

- Create a struct to hold those arrays and return it
- Pass pointers to those arrays and modify them without returning anything
- (Not elegant) Return array of those arrays
- (Not elegant) Make some global variables and modify them

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can follow to return your arrays.

1. Make a Structure with your three arrays and return the structure
2. Pass the reference to the three arrays in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return more than one value at a time in C, so your choices are:
1) Access them globally.
2) Send references (pointers) into the function.
3) Make all three of them into one struct and return that.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour, and implement 3D arrays as

```
  double *fac_x = malloc(Nx * Ny * Nz * sizeof(double));

  fac_x[z*Ny*Nx + y * Nx + x] = 123.0;
```

Now all the syntactical complications fall away. You still need to return three double *s, which entails taking double **s as parameters. That's tolerable. double **** parameters are not.

Comment: Minor: good to use `sizeof(double) * Nx * Ny * Nz` to insure `size_t` math in the multiplication.  `sizeof *fac_x  * Nx * Ny * Nz` is even better.

Comment: Using a single pointer, you are forcing it to allocate a single piece of memory chunk, whereas for 3D...it could be done in separate memory chunks.

Comment: No it can't. C arrays must be contiguous in memory. You can use similar syntax to create arrays of pointers, but that's not what the OP is doing.

Comment: sorry..my bad..he is anyways using static arrays. So, this won't have any effect. unable to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a non static array (1D, 2D or 3D) from a function results in troubles because those arrays haves local scope, you can use dynamic memory, in this case a pointer to a 3D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *func(void)
{
    double (*ptr)[3][4][5] = calloc(3, sizeof *ptr);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ptr[0][0][0][0] = 1.1;
    ptr[1][1][1][1] = 2.2;
    ptr[2][2][2][2] = 3.3;
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    double (*ptr)[3][4][5] = func();

    printf("%f\n", ptr[0][0][0][0]);
    printf("%f\n", ptr[1][1][1][1]);
    printf("%f\n", ptr[2][2][2][2]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to actually return an array is to return a structure or union type with that array as a member.  This involves copying the array contents, which could present an efficiency problem.  More importantly, however, this is viable only if the array dimensions (your `Nx`, `Ny`, and `Nz`) are compile-time constants.  Example:

```
#define Nx 5
#define Ny 7
#define Nz 10

struct arrays {
    double fac_x[Ny][Nx][Nz];
    double fac_y[Ny][Nx][Nz];
    double fac_z[Ny][Nx][Nz];
};

struct arrays foo() {
    struct arrays rval;

    // ... fill in the elements of rval ...

    return rval;
}
```

Otherwise, you cannot return arrays at all.  You could return a struct or array of pointers to the arrays or to their first elements (provided again that at least the last two dimensions are compile-time constants), but although that might serve your purpose, it is not the same thing.

More importantly, the arrays you are declaring in your function have lifetime limited to the scope in which they are declared.  Although you can obtain and even return a pointers to or into them, **such pointers will be invalid** after the function returns.

If you want to allocate space inside your function whose lifetime extends past the function's return, you need dynamic allocation via `malloc()` or `calloc()`.  Supposing that you want to give the caller access to the allocated space, I recommend using output parameters (pointers) to convey the information back.  Example:

```
int foo(unsigned Nx, unsigned Ny, unsigned Nz, double(*fac_x)[Nx][Nz],
        double(*fac_y)[Nx][Nz], double(*fac_z)[Nx][Nz]) {
    double (*tx)[Nx][Nz] = malloc(Ny * sizeof(*tx));

    if (!tx) {
        return -1;
    }

    double (*ty)[Nx][Nz] = malloc(Ny * sizeof(*ty));

    if (!ty) {
        free(tx);
        return -1;
    }

    double (*tz)[Nx][Nz] = malloc(Ny * sizeof(*tz));

    if (!tz) {
        free(tx);
        free(ty);
        return -1;
    }

    // ... fill tx, ty, and tz ...

    // supposing no errors have occurred:
    fac_x = tx;
    fac_y = ty;
    fac_z = tz;
    return 0;
}
```

This would be called like so:

```
int caller(unsigned Nx, unsigned Ny, unsigned Nz) {
    if (Nx == 0 || Ny == 0 || Nz == 0) {
        // error: invalid dimensions
        return -1;
    }

    // Note: these are pointers to arrays, not arrays themselves.
    double (*fac_x)[Nx][Nz];
    double (*fac_y)[Nx][Nz];
    double (*fac_z)[Nx][Nz];

    if (foo(Nx, Ny, Nz, fac_x, fac_y, fac_z)) {
        // handle error ...
    }

    // We are now responsible for freeing fac_x, fac_y, and fac_z

    // do stuff ... with fac_x[p][q][r], etc. ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There could be multiple solutions:

> **USING 4D-ARRAY RETURN**

```
double**** getArrays();
```

> **USING 4D-ARRAY OUTPUT PARAMETERS:**

***Signature:***

```
void getArrays(double****, double****, double****)
```

***Calling:***

```
double*** array1 = NULL;
double*** array2 = NULL;
double*** array3 = NULL;
void getArrays(&array1, &array2, &array3)
```

> **USING Structure:**

```
typedef struct{
  double*** array1;
  double*** array2;
  double*** array3;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct getArrays(); //prototype 1
void getArrays(MyStruct*) //prototype 2
```

> **USING 2D VOID POINTER OUTPUT PARAMETERS: (if passing 4D parameters is not convenient)**

***Signature:***

```
void getArrays(void**, void**, void**)
```

***Calling:***

```
void* array1 = NULL;
void* array2 = NULL;
void* array3 = NULL;
void getArrays(&array1, &array2, &array3)
double*** ar1 = (double***)array1;
...
```

Comment: NMDV, but `****` programming is not popular.  Certainly introducing `void *` does not help much either.

Comment: @chux I know that `****` programming is not good and not preferred, but if we are dealing with 3D arrays, this is the option we have. Taking 1D array has two bad effects: 1. it requires complete memory chunk as one, which could be avoided in 3D pointers, 2. the index multiplication lies at user end which is more error prone than using array indices.

Comment: To be clear "NMDV" is "not-my-down-vote".  I am simply commenting per your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574817/how-to-return-three-3d-arrays-in-c/41575091?noredirect=1#comment70355106_41575091).  No need to address [your rational](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574817/how-to-return-three-3d-arrays-in-c/41575091?noredirect=1#comment70355297_41575091) to me.  Better to improve your post with your reasons as that allows the DVer to change the vote.

Comment: @chux Sorry, if my above comment seems disturbing...but I already know the meaning of NMDV